# How to configure pom.xml of Maven project correctly with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-compiler-plugin

I have two different projects. Both of them have this class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v95.network.Network;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Optional;


public class CrawlingLinks {

  public static List<String> crawlingLinks(String url) {

    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
    devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));

    devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), entry -> {
        urls.add(entry.getRequest().getUrl());
    });

    driver.get(url);
    driver.quit();

    return urls;
  }
}
```

But in one project everything works, and in another in line 18 the error:

```
The 'getDevTools' method cannot be resolved in 'ChromeDriver'
```

happens.

---

Pom file error prone project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>-</groupId>
<artifactId>-</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description>111</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https:/repositories/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https:/repositories/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

---

Pom file of working project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>For_Tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https:repositories</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>hrepositories/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I use JDK version 11. I realized that the problem is in the parent tag. What is wrong? But how to fix it?

[image: Error's screen]

Answer (score 1):

Selenium jars are best compiled with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) jars. So you need to adjust the following:

- *`<maven.compiler.source>`*
- *`<maven.compiler.target>`*

---

### Solution

Effectively, you need to replace:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

with:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I am required to use JDK 11, is there a solution?

Comment: Eclipse will still continue to use _JDK 11_. Only Selenium jar compilation with be done through _JDK 8_.

Answer (score 0):

I just used selenium-java version 3.141.59 and this resolved my issue